# Where do I put brake fluid in a 89’ Fleetwood bounder motorhome

Tags: engine

I can’t find the resivour I don’t know how to access it

Answer (score 2):

From page 43 of the manual, [available online](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/849853/Fleetwood-Bounder-1989.html?page=55#manual):

> On Chevrolet chassis, the master cylinder is located under the driver's compartment floor, and is reached through the left front wheel well.
> On John Deere chassis the master cylinder is located near the left front of the transmission
>
> Fill the master cylinder with a squeeze bulb or pump. Check and fill the master cylinder according to instructions in the chassis operator's manual.